# Функция mb_ereg_replace также устарела как ereg_replace? Какие есть аналоги?

Tags: php

Какие есть аналоги для `mb_ereg_replace` для работы со строкой в кодировке utf-8

Answer (score 2):

[preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.preg-replace.php) с модификатором '[`u`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)'